# jQuery fade in and out function with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parameter-passing

Im trying to make this jQuery function to allow parameters or some way of making it able to work with every element in my list.

I have a function that does what i want for the first element in the list, but doesn't work for the others. I want to know if there is a way i can pass parameters into the jQuery function so i can make the function so i can make it work with several elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#f2").click(function() {
    $("#f2").fadeOut()
    $("#f1").delay(375).fadeIn()
  });
  $("#f1").click(function() {
    $("#f1").fadeOut();
    $("#f2").delay(375).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Kentucky Dam Flood Gates Open</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc" id="f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Another Item</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc" id="f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Another Item</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc" id="f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

I expected this to work with everything that had the classes required on it and only change the ones you clicked on but that function only works for the first object in the list.

Comment: You're using IDs and not classes. This will always cause issues. Change the `f1` and `f2` to classes.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your updated code switching to classes.

You don't need to pass the selector if you are always targeting the same selectors.

You also needed to add some `prev` and `next` logic to the function, otherwise any `f2` or `f1` element that is clicked would trigger all of them on the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".f2").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $(this).next('.f1').delay(375).fadeIn();
  });
  $(".f1").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $(this).prev('.f2').delay(375).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Kentucky Dam Flood Gates Open</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Another Item</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Another Item</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

And here's the fiddle to play with:
https://jsfiddle.net/brzeLywg/

Information on previous and next:

https://api.jquery.com/next/

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and wrap your code to pass the selector and delay as params.

```
function setAnimation(firstSelector, secondSelector, delayNum) {
  $(secondSelector).click(function() {
    $(secondSelector).fadeOut()
    $(firstSelector).delay(delayNum).fadeIn()
  });
  $(firstSelector).click(function() {
    $(firstSelector).fadeOut();
    $(secondSelector).delay(delayNum).fadeIn();
  });
}
```

on your script just call the as many functions as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setAnimation("#f1", "#f2", 375);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works fine, [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mavyw6o4/)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Kentucky Dam Flood Gates Open</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Another Item</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="direction-r">
      <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <span class="flag">Another Item</span>
        <span class="time-wrapper">
                    <span class="time">Present Day</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="f2">
        <img src="images/Top-KY-Dam.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="desc f1">
        Lorem Ipsum...

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".f2").on('click', function() {
    $(".f2").fadeOut();
    $(".f1").delay(375).fadeIn();
  });
  $(".f1").on('click', function() {
    $(".f1").fadeOut();
    $(".f2").delay(375).fadeIn();
  })
})
```